# Is there a loop or a function to reduce this?

Tags: c#

I need to enable multiple textboxes and couldn't figure anything else but this:

```
textBox1.Enabled = true;
textBox2.Enabled = true;
textBox3.Enabled = true;
textBox4.Enabled = true;
textBox5.Enabled = true;
```

I was trying to reduce the line count but I couldn't find loop / function to help.

I tried this function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    (TextBox(i)).enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: By the way _"Reducing Kine Count"_ isn't really a great goal. Increasing _"Readability"_ or _"Maintainability"_ are good goals. If they reduce the line count, then good

Answer (score 4):

If enabling/disabling these controls is a common operation, you can simply encapsulate it into its own method.  For example:

```
private void SetTextBoxesEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = enabled;
    textBox2.Enabled = enabled;
    textBox3.Enabled = enabled;
    textBox4.Enabled = enabled;
    textBox5.Enabled = enabled;
}
```

Then any time you want to perform this operation you'd just invoke that method:

```
SetTextBoxesEnabled(true);
```

---

If you really want to make use of a loop, you can store these controls in a collection at the class level.  For example:

```
private IEnumerable<TextBox> TextBoxes;
```

and in the constructor:

```
TextBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
```

Then you can loop over that collection wherever you like:

```
foreach (vat tb in TextBoxes)
    tb.Enabled = true;
```

---

Other options include searching for them by their name in the form's `Controls` (I'm assuming WinForms here?), or perhaps grouping them in a kind of container control and looping over *its* child controls.  But honestly I wouldn't recommend coupling this concept with the UI.  Either encapsulate the common repeated actions in a method and/or group the related objects in a collection.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach (var tb in new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 })
{
    tb.Enabled = true;
}
```

i.e., build a temporary array on the fly, iterate over it, setting the property. You could do this with a LINQ `Select` on that same array as well